# InDesign: Is there a way to ask InDesign not to remove a space behind a selected text when deleting the text?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting

When I select a text and delete it, InDesign also automatically deletes a space behind the text as well. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

No, it has been like that for a long time. They probably had this idea to avoid leaving double spaces in stories when sections are edited out.

Comment: Ah OK. Thank you for your answer. I thought there's a checkbox buried somewhere. I'll just get used to this behaviour then!

Answer (score 1):

What's more annoying is when ID *doesn't* remove trailing spaces before a linefeed and the space is used to calculate centering, throwing things off.

I don't think there's a fix for what you're asking.

InDesign appears to *remove* spaces if a glyph follows them.... but *leaves* spaces if no glyph, or a linefeed, follows them.

I have filed Adobe bug reports regarding this issue... but that was many, many, years ago and the behavior hasn't changed.

Comment: I didn't notice this behaviour before and wow, this is odd indeed. I couldn't think of any purpose that leaving that trailing space intact could serve.